# charAt(0) gives java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

`String.charAt(0)` is giving `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` even though the `String` is not empty

```
public class Mainc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int T;
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inp2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        T = inp.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            String u = "";
            String l = "";
            String s = inp2.nextLine();
            while (s != null) {
                char ch = s.charAt(0);
                if (Character.isLowerCase(ch))
                    l += ch;
                else 
                    u += ch;
                s = s.substring(1);
            }
            if (u.length() > l.length())
                System.out.println(u);
            else
                System.out.println(l); 
        }
    }
}
```

It's supposed to give an all uppercase `String` or all lowercase `String` depending on which is bigger or an all uppercase `String` if they were both equal length but it gives runtime error `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`
even though the `String` is not empty and the `charAt()` function is at index `0`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First step is to change while like `while(s!=null && !s.isEmpty())` and see if you get error.

Comment: The `String` is definitely empty if `charAt(0)` is out of bounds. That is a certainly, sure as the `String` is not `null`. Work from that assumption, not from the assumption that the JDK is somehow broken. Step through your code with a debugger, or on pen and paper; what happens to `s` if it has a length of exactly `1` on the second iteration? What is the length of the `String` returned by `substring(1)`?

Comment: it did solve the problem thank you very much but can you explain why did it happen even tho the string was never empty?

Comment: @lei as I said in my comment, the `String` is of course empty.

Comment: @lei "empty" is not the same as "null": `System.out.println("".isEmpty());` prints true; `System.out.println("" == null);` prints false.

Comment: @AndyTurner looking at the code, I think it might be bracket confusion; there's an `else` with no brackets and the substring indented too but obviously outside the `else`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider ok got it now Thank you, and Thanks for the solution@KunLun

Comment: @lei Please consider accepting the answer that best answers your question by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop loops through the string `s`, checks each character, adds that character to `u` or `l`, and then removes it from `s`. But what happens when all the characters are removed? `s` is now empty, but the while loop still executes, because `s` is not null (null and the empty string are different things!) This means that you would call `s.charAt(0)` when `s` is empty, which causes the crash.

To fix this, you can change the while loop conditions to "`s` is not empty" instead. You don't need to check if `s` is null because it comes from `Scanner.nextLine`, which shouldn't return null.

```
while (!s.isEmpty()) {
    char ch = s.charAt(0);
    if (Character.isLowerCase(ch))
        l += ch;
    else u += ch;
    s = s.substring(1);
}
```

You can improve your code further by not removing the character from `s` in each iteration. Instead, use a for loop with an index to loop through the string. Also, you should use a `StringBuilder` when concatenating strings in a loop. Both of these will avoid creating unnecessary string objects.

```
StringBuilder u = new StringBuilder(); // notice the change to StringBuilder here
StringBuilder l = new StringBuilder();
String s = inp2.nextLine();

for (int j = 0 ; j < s.length() ; j ++) {
    char ch = s.charAt(j);
    if (Character.isLowerCase(ch))
        l.append(ch);
    else u.append(ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

even your s value is `""(blank)` its still going in while loop as its not null after finish all chars so use length  `while(s.length() > 0)` should work.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int T;

        Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inp2=new Scanner(System.in);
        T=inp.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
            String u=""; String l="";

            String s=inp2.nextLine();
            while(s.length() > 0){
                char ch=s.charAt(0);
                if(Character.isLowerCase(ch))
                    l+=ch;
                else u+=ch;
                s = s.substring(1);}
            if(u.length()>l.length())
                System.out.println(u);
            else System.out.println(l);
        }
    }
}
```